# How using 'tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn ' to feed a multihead tensorflow model for multitask learning?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I'm trying to feed a tensorflow multihead model with a pandas dataframe.

The input function is following :

```
feature_column_names = [...]

input_fn_test_action = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x=test_preflop_dataframe[feature_column_names],
        y=test_preflop_dataframe[['target1','target2']],
        batch_size=BATCH,
        num_epochs=EPOCHS,
        shuffle=True,
        queue_capacity=1000,
        target_column='target'
    )
```

It seems working.

Then I build the multiheaded model as following :

```
feature_columns = [ ... ]


head1 = tf.estimator.MultiLabelHead(n_classes = 4,
                                    weight_column=weights,
                                    label_vocabulary=Action_vocab,
                                    loss_reduction=tf.losses.Reduction.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE,
                                    loss_fn=None,
                                    name='head1'
                                    )

head2 = tf.estimator.RegressionHead(label_dimension=1,
                                    weight_column=weights,
                                    loss_reduction=tf.losses.Reduction.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE,
                                    loss_fn=None,
                                    inverse_link_fn=None,
                                    name='head2'
                                    )
                                    
multi_head = tf.estimator.MultiHead([head1, head2])   

model1 = tf.estimator.DNNEstimator(head = multi_head,
                                   hidden_units = [14,9,6],
                                   feature_columns = feature_columns,
                                   model_dir='./Model3',
                                   optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LRATE, beta_1= 0.9,beta_2=0.999, epsilon = 1e-08),
                                   activation_fn=tf.nn.softmax,
                                   dropout=DROPOUT,
                                   config=tf.estimator.RunConfig().replace(save_summary_steps=10,save_checkpoints_secs=60),
                                   warm_start_from=None,
                                   batch_norm=True
                                   )
```

Seems working too...

But when I try to train with this :

```
    hookModel1 = tf.estimator.experimental.stop_if_no_decrease_hook(model1, metric_name='average_loss', max_steps_without_decrease=5000, min_steps=5000,run_every_secs=120, run_every_steps=None,)
    
    train_spec1 = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=input_fn_train_action,hooks=[hookModel1])
    
    eval_spec1 = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=input_fn_test_action,start_delay_secs = 60,throttle_secs = 60)

    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(model1, train_spec1, eval_spec1)
```

I've got this error :

Traceback (most recent call last): (...)
raise ValueError('labels has missing values for head(s): {}'.format(
ValueError: labels has missing values for head(s): ['head1', 'head2']

I guess the model cannot associate each head with corresponding label because 'tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn' returns a dict of feature but an array of labels (two in this case) but without name to associate with heads and multihead have to be fed with a dict of labels with head specification `{'head1' : [label_array1], 'head2' : [label_array2]}`.

Is someone has a solution for this ?

Comment: Same problem here : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19182

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the issue described here is solved in TF 2.3:  github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19182

Now, tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn returns feature dict and label dict if a list of pandas series is provided. The labels flags are the pd's header.

Then the solution is to give each head the same name than the label in pd's serie !!